# C++ - Using DirectSound or XAudio2 with EAX

Tags: c++, audio, directx, directsound, xaudio2

Is there any sample/tutorial/resource of using EAX with DirectSound or XAudio2 in C++? I cant find anything and I really need that for my game engine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, DirectSound is ancient at this point. It is still supported for older games, and the DirectSound 8 headers are in the Windows SDK, but there's been no samples or documentation updates for it in over a decade.

The Windows audio driver model (WDM), however, does not support hardware audio mixing like that required for Creative EAX. Support for this was removed as of Windows Vista, so EAX cannot be used through either DirectSound or XAudio2.

To sum up the Windows Vista driver model changes w.r.t to DirectSound:

- `LOC_SOFTWARE` buffers can support surround sound multi-channel formats. On Windows XP only mono or stereo were supported for `LOC_SOFTWARE`.
- `LOC_HARDWARE` buffers are not supported.
- Effects (I3DL, EAX, etc.) are not supported through DirectSound.
- DirectSound 3D positioning is limited to mono sounds.

XAudio2 supports environmental reverb and 3D audio positioning including multi-channel sources, all done in software.

> XAudio 2.8 is in the Windows SDK, although you need to use the legacy DirectX SDK for XAudio 2.7 to target Windows 7 or Windows Vista--see [this post](https://walbourn.github.io/xaudio2-and-windows-8/) for details. Samples can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples). The [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK) is very useful abstraction for using XAudio2 from C++.

**UPDATE:** XAudio 2.9 is now available on Windows 7 SP1 or later via the [XAudio2Redist](https://aka.ms/xaudio2redist) and avoids any need to use the legacy DirectX SDK or legacy DirectSetup deployment.

To get hardware access for features like EAX, you have to use a 3rd party solution like OpenAL. See the [Creative site](http://support.creative.com/kb/ShowArticle.aspx?sid=25937) for more.

Comment: I'm curious about what dsound documentation/example updates you would consider to be beneficial.  I've been setting up a simple looping buffer in DS8 and the docs/examples are pretty straightforward so far.  Am I hindering my progress with old docs?

Comment: You are coding to an emulated API. For example, there's no such thing as a "primary buffer" being actually related to the hardware. DirectSound on modern versions of Windows is just emulated on top of the same mixing software that is used by XAudio2. It's purpose is for backcompat, but new applications can take advantage of lower latency, more features, and a cleaner "packed-based" design of XAudio2 that leaves all the source audio sample memory under application control. IOW, you are doing a lot of extra copies of data using DirectSound.